# Tensorflow: RNN example, where do word embeddings come from

Tags: python, tensorflow

There is a Tensorflow LSTM example here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py

I'm trying to understand where the word embeddings come from.

See, there's this code:

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    embedding = tf.get_variable(
        "embedding", [vocab_size, size], dtype=data_type())
    inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, input_.input_data)
```

I have a sense of what the `embedding` variable should hold (as explained, say, in this example: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec. But there has to be some magic to get the work done (training an embedding model, etc.)

And I don't see anything like that in the project code. I can't find anything that could generate simple one-hot encoded vectors either. It's just replacing words with their integer IDs and then reshaping the data in the reader code (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/reader.py).

What am I missing? I'm really sorry if this is something blatantly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure but this is what I understood:

I think embedding a is trainable tensor. tf.get_variable() gets an existing variable with these parameters or create a new one if there is none existing.

If initializer is None, a glorot_uniform_initializer will be used.

Based on vocab size, we initialize big embedding matrix and let it find best embedding values for our vocabulary.

Comment: back-propagation do the work of finding gradients and updating them.